# Create properties in class from list / attribute in __init__

Tags: python, properties, setter, getter, setattribute

I have a piece of hardware I write a class for which has multiple inputs. Each input (channel) has a name, so I created a list:

```
CHANNELS = {"T0": 0, "Tend": 1, "A": 2, "B": 3, "C" : 4, "D" : 5,
    "E" : 6, "F" : 7, "G" : 8, "H" : 9}
```

Now I would like to create a property to access the value of each channel:

```
@property
def readT0(self)
    return self._query("REQUEST STRING 0")
    # the request string expects a number, instead of the real name T0

@property
def readTend(self)
    return self._query("REQUEST STRING 1")
```

etc.

I would rather do something like this (less source code):

```
def read(self, channel)
    return self._query("REQUEST STRING %s" % channel)
```

and use some kind of translation to create the attributes:

```
def __init__ bla bla:
    bla bla

    for x in CHANNELS:
        setattr(self, "read" + str(x), self.read(CHANNELS[x])
```

so

```
class.readA    # channel A value: 10
> 10
class.readT0   # channel T0 value: 0.11
> 0.11
```

This way, if the hardware uses more channels, I can just add to the `CHANNELS` dictionary. Or is there a better way?

Since I only want to read values, I would stop here. But is there a way to combine this with a setter, too?

edit:

I have to clarify: I don't want to change the dictionary or access the values of the dictionary at runtime, I want to use it on class creation to create multiple attributes for a hardware to read the hardware values.

The hardware is a ADC with channels. I can read the ADC value of each channel with

```
someclass._query("REQUEST STRING i")
# i is the channel number and returns the ADC value (e.g. 10.45 V)
```

Comment: Why do you want `read` in there? Wouldn't `class.A0` be neater? How does `_query`correspond to the dictionary?

Comment: Hi, `class.T0`or `class.A`would indeed be neater, but the channels have different properties, so `read` might well change to `class.delayT0` and `class.offsetT0` ... Don't know what you mean by correspond: `_query()`is a com function to read from the hardware.

Comment: don't use properties for something that has a side effect, that's awful, use methods instead. Remember the [zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): explicit is better than implicit. A property is for hiding a small operation on an attribute, not disguising a costly method in a simple attribute.

Comment: Why does my example has a side effect? I have a attribute, which I will use in other more complex methods. But here I just want to read and maybe change the value (which can be changed from the hardware to) and I might want to do a small operation on it...

Comment: you said _query is a function to read from the hardware, this is a side-effect, and is costly, it should be explicit.

Comment: I see what you mean. But heaving something like `someclass.get_T0()` and `someclass.set_T0()` looks more awful to me. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that @property is the way I will go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to dynamically create functions and make them members of your class instances, you can use `lambda`:

```
CHANNELS = {"T0": 0, "Tend": 1, "A": 2, "B": 3, "C" : 4, "D" : 5,
    "E" : 6, "F" : 7, "G" : 8, "H" : 9}

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        for x in CHANNELS:
            setattr(self, "read{}".format(x), lambda x=x: self.read(CHANNELS[x]))

    def read(self, channel):
        return self._query("REQUEST STRING {}".format(channel))

    def _query(self, q):
        print "query {}".format(q)


f = Foo()
f.readT0()
f.readTend()
f.readA()
f.readB()
f.readC()
```

It works but there are a few drawbacks:

- it creates the same set of functions for each and any *instance* (for no reason in this case since all instances are based on the same `CHANNELS` definition)
- these functions are not documented and won't appear in `dir(Foo)` or `help(Foo)`

jonsharpe's `__getattr__` solution solves the first point but not the second. The simplest solution here is to use a class decorator that will add the getters (either as methods or properties, it's up to you) on the class itself, ie (properties version):

```
def with_channel_props(cls):
    for x in cls.CHANNELS:
        getter = lambda self, x=x: self.read(self.CHANNELS[x])
        setattr(cls, "{}".format(x), property(getter))
    return cls


@with_channel_props
class Baaz(object):
    CHANNELS = {
        "T0": 0, "Tend": 1, "A": 2, "B": 3, "C" : 4, "D" : 5,
        "E" : 6, "F" : 7, "G" : 8, "H" : 9
        }

    def read(self, channel):
        return self._query("REQUEST STRING {}".format(channel))

    def _query(self, q):
        return "query {}".format(q)

b = Baaz()
print b.T0
print b.Tend
print b.A
print b.B
print b.C
```

Now you can use `dir(Baaz)` and `help(Baaz)` or any other introspection mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

I *think* this is what you want:

```
class Something(object):

    CHANNELS = {"T0": 0, "Tend": 1, "A": 2, "B": 3, "C": 4, "D": 5,
                "E": 6, "F": 7, "G": 8, "H": 9}

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """Handle missing attributes."""
        if name.startswith('read') and name[4:] in self.CHANNELS:
            return self.CHANNELS[name[4:]]
        return super(Something, self).__getattribute__(name)
```

In use:

```
>>> thing = Something()
>>> thing.readA
2
>>> thing.readT0
0
>>> thing.garbage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in __getattr__
AttributeError: 'Something' object has no attribute 'garbage'
```

You can then use these channel attributes in your call to `_query` as required. If you want to assign to the dictionary too, you'd need to implement [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__).

Comment: Hi, I don't want to read from the dictionary but from an ADC input. CHANNELS is only to translate from `A`to 2, cause the hardware uses numbers as channel identifiers.

Comment: @Wolf82 yes, this just shows you how to use `__getattr__` to handle missing attributes and get the relevant channel number from the dictionary. Integrating that into your code base is your job!