# Creating object-oriented wrapper for API with generic object wrapping data object

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to create a Python wrapper for an API that works like this.

```
>>> api = APIClient(client_id, client_secret)
>>> api.Project.get(name="proj_name")  # returns Project object of that specific name
```

How do I have `Project` inside `api`? I don't want to have it be a nested class because there are many other data objects and nesting will create a big file. I would also be happy if someone suggested a better design for this specific task.

`APIClient.py`

```
class APIClient(object):
    def __init__(self, username, password):
       self.client_id = username
       self.client_secret = password
       self.headers = {"Content-Type" : "application/json"}

    def _get_request(self, params):
       r =requests.get(url, params = params, headers = self.headers, auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
```

`project.py`

```
class Project(object):
  def __init__(self, name, orgname):
     self.name = name
     self.orgname = orgname

  @classmethod
  def get(name):
     r = ...  # should call _get_request in APIClient
```

`customer.py`

```
class Customer(object):
  def __init__(self, name, address):
     self.name = name
     self.address.address

  @classmethod
  def get(name):
     r = ...  # should call _get_request with name and address as param
```

Comment: You could implement `__getattr__` for missing attributes on `APIClient` and look up the API object classes in a dictionary `{'Project': Project, ...}`. I did something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38265400/3001761. But note that getting those classes to call *back* to `_get_request` might be trickier. You could consider an interface more like `api.get(Project, name='proj_name')`, that might be easier to implement.

Comment: Thank you that solves the issue. I also agree that getting call back to _get_request will unnecessarily complicate the code. What if I made APIClient a Base class and Project inherit APIClient?

Comment: Yes, that would work, but then users would have to initialise each one with their credentials, rather than giving them to one central client object. Why not have a look at how existing API wrappers do it (there are hundreds on PyPI, for example)?